# How to get Coldfusion 10 to work with IIS 10 in Windows 10

Tags: iis, coldfusion, windows-10, coldfusion-10

Windows 10 comes with IIS 10, and ColdFusion 10 doesn't seem to like it.  ColdFusion 10 installs fine, but when it comes time to create connectors (either during installation or by using the tool at `C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\runtime\bin\wsconfig.exe`), it fails.  The error message I get is that it doesn't support IIS 10.

[image]

This connector is required to set up the `CFIDE` and `jakarta` virtual folders in IIS.

Any way around this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An already deleted blog post from *blogs.coldfusion.com* (http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/configuring-connectors-manually-for-iis-10) once stated the following

> With Windows 10 out, there is a problem that most of the ColdFusion
>   customers will face, configuring connectors for IIS 10. Wsconfig, the
>   connector configuration tool, only supports till IIS 8.x. While the
>   ColdFusion team is working on this issue and will try to provide the
>   fix for it as soon as possible, there is already a [KB article](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion10-iis-manual-connector-configuration.html) which
>   can be referred for configuring the connectors manually. Although the
>   article was originally written for CF10, it can be used for CF11 also.
>   After following all the steps in the article, you need to do one more
>   thing. Add index.cfm as default document for your website in IIS.
>
> This solution is only recommended for development environments as
>   through testing of the connectors with IIS 10 is still going on. So
>   for production machines, you should wait for the actual release from
>   Adobe.

**UPDATE**

> Important update: Note that ColdFusion 10 and 11 [have been updated to
>   support Windows 10](http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/coldfusion-11-update-7-and-coldfusion-10-update-18-are-now-available), a couple months after this blog post was first
>   written. Consider applying that update rather than this manual
>   configuration.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Windows 10 Pro, you also have the option of running a Virtual Machine in the included Hyper-V offering.  Instructions on how to enable Hyper-V are found here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2014/10/02/step-by-step-creating-and-running-a-windows-10-vm-on-windows-8-1.aspx

Simply spin up a version of Windows required.

Answer (score 0):

apply latest hotfix for cf 11 hotfix_019.jar. that will fix the issue above